# How to add curvy designs in a container in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a container with similar design like this:

[image]

Comment: Easiest solution is to use SVG image of that background and give it dynamic height which can adjust according to the screen height.

Comment: Maybe like this  https://pub.dev/packages/proste_bezier_curve

Answer (score 1):

you can use [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers)